# Unable to alert jquery slider value

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm writing a code where there are 3 Jquery sliders present, here when I change I want to alert the 3 sliders values.

Here I've 2 problems.

1. I'm unable to alert the value of the slider that is changed.
2. I'm unable to know on how I can alert all 3 sliders value.

Here is my code.

```
$("#a").slider({
    range: "min",
    orientation: "vertical",
    step: 1,
    value: 10,
    max: 14,
    min: 8.5,
    create: function (event, ui) {
        $("#a").find(".ui-slider-handle").append('<input id="sliderValueA" />')
    },
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#sliderValueA").val(ui.value + "%");
    },
    change: function (event, ui) {
        $(".target-value").text("Hi");
        alert($("#sliderValueA").val);
    }
});


$("#b").slider({
    range: "min",
    orientation: "vertical",
    value: 0.9,
    step: 0.2,
    min: 0.4,
    max: 1.98,
    create: function (event, ui) {
        $("#b").find(".ui-slider-handle").append('<input id="sliderValueB" />')
    },
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#sliderValueB").val(ui.value + "g");
    },
    change: function (event, ui) {
        $(".target-value").text("Hi");
        alert($("#sliderValueB").val);
    }
});

$("#c").slider({
    range: "min",
    orientation: "vertical",
    value: 20,
    min: 6,
    max: 155,
    create: function (event, ui) {
        $("#c").find(".ui-slider-handle").append('<input id="sliderValueC" />')
    },
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#sliderValueC").val(ui.value + "%");
    },
    change: function (event, ui) {
        $(".target-value").text("Hi");
        alert($("#sliderValueC").val);
    }
});
```

please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> 1. I'm unable to alert the value of the slider that is changed.

That happen because you've a typo in your alerts code, `.val` should be `.val()` like:

```
$("#sliderValueC").val();
```

Instead of:

```
$("#sliderValueC").val
```

> 2. I'm unable to know on how I can alert all 3 sliders value.

You could create a function that alert the three values and call it instead of alert in every `change` callback:

```
function alertValues(){
   $(".target-value").text("Hi");

    alert( $("#sliderValueA").val() );
    alert( $("#sliderValueB").val() );
    alert( $("#sliderValueC").val() );

    //Or

    var a = $("#sliderValueA").val();
    var b = $("#sliderValueB").val();
    var c = $("#sliderValueC").val();
    alert('Slider A :'+ a + ', Slider B :' + b + ', Slider C :' + c);
}
```

Then call it like :

```
change: function (event, ui) {
    alertValues();
}
//Or
change: alertValues
```

Answer (score 0):

> when I change I want to alert the 3 sliders values.

You can concatenate the value of each slider, and use `\n` to put each value on a new line within the alert.

Here is the code you need for your alert:

```
alert('Slider A is: ' + $('#a').slider('value') + '%\nSlider B is: ' + $('#b').slider('value') + 'g\nSlider C is: ' + $('#c').slider('value') + '%');
```

So your code would look like this:

```
$("#a").slider({
    range: "min",
    orientation: "vertical",
    step: 1,
    value: 10,
    max: 14,
    min: 8.5,
    create: function(event, ui) {
        $("#a").find(".ui-slider-handle").append('<input id="sliderValueA" />')
    },
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#sliderValueA").val(ui.value + "%");
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        alert('Slider A is: ' + $('#a').slider('value') + '%\nSlider B is: ' + $('#b').slider('value') + 'g\nSlider C is: ' + $('#c').slider('value') + '%');
    }
});


$("#b").slider({
    range: "min",
    orientation: "vertical",
    value: 0.9,
    step: 0.2,
    min: 0.4,
    max: 1.98,
    create: function(event, ui) {
        $("#b").find(".ui-slider-handle").append('<input id="sliderValueB" />')
    },
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#sliderValueB").val(ui.value + "g");
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        alert('Slider A is: ' + $('#a').slider('value') + '%\nSlider B is: ' + $('#b').slider('value') + 'g\nSlider C is: ' + $('#c').slider('value') + '%');
    }
});

$("#c").slider({
    range: "min",
    orientation: "vertical",
    value: 20,
    min: 6,
    max: 155,
    create: function(event, ui) {
        $("#c").find(".ui-slider-handle").append('<input id="sliderValueC" />')
    },
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#sliderValueC").val(ui.value + "%");
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        alert('Slider A is: ' + $('#a').slider('value') + '%\nSlider B is: ' + $('#b').slider('value') + 'g\nSlider C is: ' + $('#c').slider('value') + '%');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this documentation http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-value, to get the value of the slider you'd use `$( "#slider" ).slider( "value" );`

To get for all sliders, if the IDs are known you can just call the "value" attribute just like so

```
alert($("#a").slider("value") + " " + $("#b").slider("value") + " " + $("#c").slider("value"));
```

or if they are referenced by a class, you can loop over the array of sliders just like that

```
var sliderValues =  "";
$(".slider").each(() => {
    sliderValues += $(this).slider("value") + " ";
}); 
alert(sliderValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

Example Solution to get all slider values on change.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Slider - Custom handle</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #custom-handle {
    width: 3em;
    height: 1.6em;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -.8em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.6em;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    
    function alertSliderValues() {
    
        var sliderHandle1 = $("#slider1").slider("value");
        var sliderHandle2 = $("#slider2").slider("value");
        var sliderHandle3 = $("#slider3").slider("value");
    
        alert(
          "SliderHandle1=" + sliderHandle1 + 
          "\nSliderHandle2=" + sliderHandle2 + 
          "\nSliderHandle3=" + sliderHandle3
          );
    }
    
  $( function() {
   

   
    $( "#slider1").slider({
      change: function() {
        alertSliderValues();
      }
    });

    $( "#slider2").slider({
      change: function() {
        alertSliderValues();
      }
    });
    
    $( "#slider3").slider({
      change: function() {
        alertSliderValues();
      }
    });    
    
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="slider1">
</div>
<br />

<div id="slider2">
</div>
<br />
 
<div id="slider3">
</div>
<br />
 
</body>
</html>
```